# upload_video.py sample code

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, youtube-data-api

I ran this sample code as describe on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video in ubuntu 14.04 and get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "upload_video.py", line 178, in <module>
        youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
    File "upload_video.py", line 82, in get_authenticated_service
        credentials = storage.get()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 389, in get
        return self.locked_get()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/file.py", line 81, in locked_get
        credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(content)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 294, in new_from_json
        module_name = data['_module']
KeyError: '_module'
```

Is this problem due to missing packages or anything else?

Comment: Looks like the script can't log in to Youtube.  Did you add a valid `client_id` and `client_secret` to `client_secrets.json`?

Comment: In client_secrets.json, I have the credentials copy from Google Developer's Console OAuth 2.0 client IDs. I aslo have a upload_video.py-oauth2.json file containing the service account credentials for the same project.